# Relationship between smoothness and Lipschitzness

Tags: convex-optimization, vector-analysis, lipschitz-functions, smooth-functions

Given a convex function $f:\Omega\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ has function value bounded $|f(x)|\leq B$, diameter of the convex domain bounded $\|x-y\|_2\leq D, x,y\in \Omega$ and $\beta$ smoothness: $\|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\|_2\leq \beta\|x-y\|_2$. How do we determine the Lipschitz constant for $f$? I found in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kfir-Levy/publication/303458146_Bandit_Convex_Optimization_Towards_Tight_Bounds/links/587cb74d08ae9275d4e6dd42/Bandit-Convex-Optimization-Towards-Tight-Bounds.pdf?origin=publication_detail) that the Lipschitz constant is at most $\frac{2B}{D}+\frac{\beta D}{2}$ but I do not know how to derive it. Do anyone have some idea about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because the boundness of $f$, we have $f\in L^{\infty}$. Due to the smoothness, we have $\nabla f\in Lip$, that is  $\nabla^2 f\in L^{\infty}$. Therefore, we may use the Gagliardo–Nirenberg interpolation theorem to get an answer... However, I believe that there may be a direct method.

**Update:** we can use taylor's formular.
$$
f(y)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)\cdot(y-x)+\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2f(\xi)(y-x)^2
$$
It implies that

$$
|\nabla f|\le |\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}|+\frac{\nabla^2 f(\xi)}{2}|y-x|\le \frac{2B}{|y-x|}+\frac{\beta}{2} |y-x|
$$

$$
\min_{0\le |x-y|\le L} \frac{2B}{|y-x|}+\frac{\beta}{2} |y-x| =\frac{2B}{L}+\frac{\beta}{2}L
$$

the last equality needs the assumption that $L^2\le \frac{4B}{\beta}$.

Comment: Thanks but I do not quite get the inequality. First, I think $\nabla f(x) (y-x)$ should be inner product as the gradient is a vector. Second, as $y-x$ is also a vector, I do not see how the inequality is obtained from the above. Any Cauchy-Schwarts is used here?

Comment: @PieForever We can make $y-x \parallel \nabla f(x)$.

Comment: I think then 2B/|y-x| can be infinitely large if y can not extend in the direction of $\nabla f(x)$.

Comment: Actually I just found that there is a counter example for the above argument....

Comment: Sure, you are right.